# Google chrome extension - Is there a way to add a listener to text select/highlight event on any tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to trigger a block of code every time the user selects/highlights some text on any of the tabs.

I am able to run the javascript when I highlight some text and then click on my extension.
I have already read some of the chrome apis but none of them seem to work.
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    alert(window.getSelection().toString());
});
```

I am not able to run the code as soon as I highlight some text. Is there an API that already handles that?

Comment: You need a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). It'll run in each web page according to the `"matches"` rule, and it can send messages to your background script. More in the documentation.

Comment: are you solved this problem? @Karan Khurana

Answer (score 1):

You should just add a buffer:

#### Store selection

As you are talking about selections from any tab, You should use the [storage api](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage) and refer the [tab id](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) for further use.

```
document.onmouseup = function() { 
    chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(_tabId){
        if(_tabId){
            var _SELECTION = {};
            _SELECTION[tabId] = window.getSelection().toString();
            chrome.storage.local.set(_SELECTION, function() {
                console.log('Selection saved: ', _SELECTION[tabId]);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

#### Use it when you click on your extension

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(_tabId){
        if(_tabId){
            chrome.storage.local.get(_tabId, function(result) {
                alert('Selection restored: ' + result[tabId].txt);
            });
        }

    });
});
```

#### Manifest

Don't forget to update your manifest.json to set the according permissions

```
{
    ...

    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "tabs"
    ],

    ...
}
```

#### Note

1. I used storage.local as the clipboard should be kept on the local machine, but if you want to share it cross-machines you can use storage.sync. More to read in the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage).
2. I'd use [contextMenus](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contextMenus). It makes more sense if you highlight text to right-click and perform an action.

Comment: Is it possible to run the extension script without the need for user to click the extension? Is it possible to listen to text highlight event and trigger a javascript based on just that without the need for user to click on the extension?

Comment: Yes of course. Just add the watcher to your content_script: `document.onmouseup= function() {window.alert(window.getSelection().toString());}`